# RegExp: last symbol missing

Tags: regex, street-address

I wrote a regular expression:

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)\s(.+)[^\)]$
```

Which divides the string into street type and street name. Some streets have street location description, which i don't want to select.

Here it is:
https://regex101.com/r/j3gF5b/2

It works, but every last symbol in street name are missing. I would like to know why this happens and how to repair it?

Comment: Could you clarify: You dont want the streets with location description OR you dont want the location description itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `[^)]` matches exactly 1 character that is not `)` ... that is your missing letter from street name

You could use this:

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)\s([^\)]+?)$
```

Comment: so, how can i miss lines with brackets and not lost last symbol?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that the *negated character class* still *consumes* the matching substring. Use a *negative lookbehind* (a zero-width assertion, a non-consuming construct) after asserting the end of string/line:

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)\s(.+)$(?<!\))
                                                         ^^^^^^^
```

It will fail all the matches that end with `)`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5cSMhp/2)

Another way is via using a negative lookahead (if the regex engine doesn't support lookbehinds, as in JavaScript):

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)(?!.*\)$)\s*(.+)$
```

See [another demo](https://regex101.com/r/5cSMhp/3)

Comment: Looks like engine not support this feature, but thanks

Comment: What do you mean? Which engine are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Put it inside the capture group (and eventually exclude also the newline character):

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)\s(.*[^)\r\n])$
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eEdZhi/1)

If you only want to discard the location description and keep the rest:

```
^(проезд|пл|пр-кт|пер|наб|линия|км|б-р|аллея|кв-л)\s([^(\s]*(?:\h+[^(\s]+)*)
```

[demo](https://regex101.com/r/eEdZhi/3)